# Using Timer to delay an operation a few seconds

Tags: c#, timer

I am trying to delay my method by using a timer:

```
private System.Timers.Timer _delayTimer;

    private void delay()
    {
          _delayTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
          _delayTimer.Interval = 5000;
          //_delayTimer.Enabled = true;
          _delayTimer.Elapsed += _delayTimer_Elapsed;
          _delayTimer.Start();
          someMethod();
        }
    }

    private void _delayTimer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        // delay for 5 seconds
    }
```

When i am get into `delay()` method i want to start the timer, than i want the 5 seconds delay and only after that i want to execute `someMethod()` and currently this not happen, after execute `delay()` the `someMethod()` executed without 5 seconds delay

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your current code sets up the timer and then immediately executes `someMethod`. Instead of this, you need to put the actual method call inside your `Elapsed` handler:

```
private void delay()
{
      _delayTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
      _delayTimer.Interval = 5000;
      //_delayTimer.Enabled = true;
      _delayTimer.Elapsed += _delayTimer_Elapsed;
      _delayTimer.Start();
    }
}

private void _delayTimer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
      someMethod();
}
```

And if there's nothing else you intend to do you can simply write this inline:

```
_delayTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
_delayTimer.Interval = 5000;
_delayTimer.Elapsed += (o, e) => someMethod();
_delayTimer.Start();
```

Comment: And if someMethod() received an object as parameter and i am using Timer.Tag property to send this object to _delayTimer_Elapsed, how can i cast this object from _delayTimer_Elapsed ?

Comment: @user2214609: Cast the first argument (`sender` in the long form, `o` in the short form) to `Timer` and access its `Tag`, e.g. `(o, e) => someMethod(((Timer)o).Tag)`. Actually, in the short form you could also directly capture the parameter: `(o, e) => someMethod(_delayTimer.Tag)`.

Comment: Can i have a short example ? its hard to understand in this way (i am a new developer...), i moved the relevat code into _delayTimer_Elapsed and wants to send to this event MyObject as parameter

Comment: @user2214609: `var timer = (Timer)sender;` and then access `timer.Tag`.

Comment: I am using System.Timers.Timer _delayTimer and after MyObject object = (Timer)sender got an error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Threading.Timer' to 'my namespace'

Comment: @user2214609: `(System.Threading.Timer)sender`, that should be easy to see. In general you would want to `using System.Threading` at the top of your code file so you don't have to specify the namespace all the time.

Answer (score 6):

If you're in .Net4.5(or using BCL.Async pack) you can use `Task.Delay`

```
private async void delay()
{
    await Task.Delay(5000);
    someMethod();
}
```

If you're under .Net4.5

Try the below code. I'll suggest you to use `System.Threading.Timer`

```
var timer = new System.Threading.Timer(x => someMethod(), null, 5000, System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);\
```

Don't forget when you use Threading.Timer `someMethod` will be invoked in `ThreadPool` thread, If you're accessing UI you need to marshal the call to UI thread.

Answer (score 4):

If you want the current thread to pause for five seconds, then call `Thread.Sleep`. For example:

```
Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
DoSomething();
```

Use a timer if you want something to happen five seconds from now, while you're doing something else. When the timer elapses, the action will be executed on a thread pool thread.

Also, if you only want the timer to execute one time (rather than once every five seconds), be sure to set [AutoReset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.autoreset.aspx) to `false`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `someMethod` in the timer's Elapsed handler:

```
private void delay()
{
      _delayTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
      _delayTimer.Interval = 5000;
      _delayTimer.AutoReset = false; //so that it only calls the method once
      _delayTimer.Elapsed += (s,args) => someMethod();
      _delayTimer.Start();
}
```

You could also use `Task.Delay` instead:

```
private void delay()
{
    Task.Delay(5000)
    .ContinueWith(t => someMethod());
}
```

Comment: Might be worth noting that if `someMethod` accesses any UI components then an illegal cross thread call will occur. In order to resolve this you could pass the result of `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()` as the second argument to the `ContinueWith` method.

Answer (score 1):

```
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
                /*
                 * Here Yopur code to do some method :D
                 * */
            });
```

Comment: This is a bad solution as it will block the thread for 5 seconds.